# Result page is not coming after clicking Submit Button in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to implement one form application in spring boot by referring to the url as below:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

I am able to render the input form page then clicking on submit button. After that the page need to be rendering to result.html but it's not going to result.html page.

Please find the code as below:

```
@Controller
public class SearchByID {

    @GetMapping("/searchByID")
    public String searchByIDForm(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("searchByID", new Search());
        return "searchbyID";
    }

    @PostMapping("/searchByID")
    public String searchByIDSubmit(@ModelAttribute Search search) {

        return "result";
    }

}

result.html
==========
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>GUI Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <p th:text="'id: ' + ${search.id}" />
</body>
</html>

searchbyID.html
==============

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>GUI Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>GUI Application</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/searchByID}" th:object="${searchByID}" method="get">
        <p>ID: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Search" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help on this.

Comment: Try with `post` instead of `get` in `method="get"`.

Comment: Yes, i just tried before seeing your post and it's working. Thank You @Andrei Damian-Fekete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is Resolved by changing method to "post" from "get" as shown below:

```
form action="#" th:action="@{/searchByID}" th:object="${searchByID}" method="get">
        <p>ID: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Search" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
```